# Can anyone share their experience with SpaceNavigator 3D mouse?

Tags: 3d, hardware

I was wondering if any of you had a chance to use any of the [3Dconnexion](http://www.3dconnexion.com/) products in GIS setting? What are your experiences?

Is something like [SpaceNavigator](http://www.3dconnexion.com/products/spacenavigator.html) worth investing into?

Update: Apparently, [one million](http://www.gearthblog.com/blog/archives/2011/03/3dconnexion_sells_their_one_million.html) of them on the market.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The device gives you an extra degree of freedom when flying through 3D landscape. I bought SpaceNavigator for capturing videos in Google Earth. It works wonderfully for that purpose... However I have not found another good use for the device.

Answer (score 3):

James Fee has s[everal posts on his site](http://www.spatiallyadjusted.com/?s=space+navigator) about the Space Navigator.

Answer (score 2):

Works very well in Google Earth

http://www.gearthblog.com/blog/archives/2006/11/3dconnexion_and_goog.html

http://ogleearth.com/2006/11/3dconnexions-spacenavigator-the-review/

Demo:

http://www.gearthblog.com/blog/archives/2006/11/youtube_demo_of_spac.html